# array of structs in c-user input

Tags: c

I am new to programming in general and to `C` in particular. 
I am trying to write a program that uses an array of structs, but I am experiencing problems if that struct contains strings. 
Somehow the compiler crashes after the user has given the last input.

The struct below is just a simplified version containing only one item, because the problem seems to be reading strings into the array. 
Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct
{
    char* name;
}student;

int main()
{
    int size;
    printf("enter number of entries\n");
    scanf("%d" , &size);
    student* all=malloc(size*sizeof(student));

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("enter name\n");
        scanf("%s" , all[i].name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to `free` that memory

Comment: and don't produce any other bugs while you'll be adding this

Comment: change also `int size` to `long unsigned int` or `size_t`.

Comment: Very good that you include a minimal version of your problem and not your original code!!! That makes this a much better question than just dumping whatever you have on us. Remember to do the same for future questions.

Comment: @wiliamssidis Take a look [here](http://ideone.com/7JpnAI) too.

Comment: We still badly need a canonical duplicate for "program crashes when I try to dump stuff into the address of an uninitialized pointer" :(

Comment: Just a quick note: `Somehow the compiler crashes after the user has given the last input.` The **compiler** didn't crash but your program did.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies everyone.They helped me quite a bit

Answer (score 6):

Before taking input  `scanf("%s" , all[i].name);` , you need to allocate memory to `all[i].name` .

An example-

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    all[i].name=malloc(20*sizeof(*(all[i].name)));
    if(all[i].name!=NULL){
       printf("enter name\n");
       scanf("%19s" , all[i].name);
    }
}
//use these strings
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
       free(all[i].name);                  //free the allocated memory 
}
free(all);
```

*Or* in your structure instead of `char *` ,declare `name` as a `char` array (*if you don't want to use dynamic allocation*)-

```
typedef struct{
  char name[20];                     //give any desired size
 }student;
/*           no need to free in this case   */
```

Comment: @iharob Mentioned that .

Answer (score 0):

No memory is allocated for the students names (`char* name`), so when trying to `scanf` to that pointer, invalid memory is accessed and the program crashes.

The easiest way is to declare `name` as an array: `char name[28];`

The return value of `malloc()` needs to be checked too, in case there was  problem allocating the memory for the `students`, which would return a `NULL pointer`. At the end, the allocated memory needs to be freed with `free()`.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[28];
    unsigned int age;
} student;

int main()
{
    size_t size = 0;
    printf("\nEnter number of entries: ");
    scanf("%zu", &size);
    // add some check for size

    student* students = (student*)malloc(size * sizeof(student));

    if (students == NULL) {
        printf("\nProblem with allocating memory:\n"
               " - size: %zu\n"
               " - total size needed: %zu\n",
               size, size * sizeof(student));
        return 0;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%27s", students[i].name);
        printf(" Enter age: ");
        scanf("%u", &students[i].age);
    }

    printf("\nList of students:\n");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%s (%u)\n", students[i].name, students[i].age);
    }

    free(students); // free the allocated memory

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to clear the input buffer after using `scanf`: `while(getchar() != '\n');`

Comment: I edited your answer: the format specifiers for `scanf` were also wrong.

Comment: @d3l - Thanks, I updated the format specifiers (although `"%zu"` might not be supported on all (older) compilers). I don't think clearing `\n` is needed here since we're not scanning for chars.